# How to setup a router/access point that a reset will make it disconnect from the network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, security

So I have a main router and plenty of access points (precisely: Wi-Fi routers configured to be access points) connected to the main router. The access points can be physically accessed by the public, so anybody could reset it and connect to the otherwise private LAN/internet with the default credentials.

Is there a network topology or some kind of rules I can set so when somebody reset the access point it has to be reconfigured in a specific way so it can work again?

Answer (score 0):

**Is there a solution?** yes there is.

**Should you do it that way?** Definitely not.

If I got you right, you have this setup (for the sake of simplicity only with one access point)

```
Internet(I) 
   |
Router(R) ---- AccessPoint(AP) ---- ThePublic(P)
   |
Some other LAN devices(L)
```

And right now, you somehow logically ensure that P can not access L or I but only other Ps? And because P has physical access to AP you want to prevent what happens P presses the reset button.

The problem is, someone with physical access to the AP could just pull out the cable and connect directly to your network and attack it. So doing some clever configuration on the AP does not help.

What you want is a setup where the router manages who can access what on your network. (assuming P can not physically access R)

There are several possibilities to achieve security here. One would be using VLANs. So setting each port of R where an AP is connected to belong to some specific VLAN (Access port). It would not work if the AP would do the VLAN tagging, because then the attacker could try to tag his own packets to belong to another VLAN. This would be called trunk port.

You could use this tutorial as a primer on VLANs: 
http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/lanwan/lanwan-howto/30071-vlan-how-to-segmenting-a-small-lan

Comment: The Wi-Fi is password protected and there isn't SSID broadcast. Who has the password can access anything who don't those shouldn't. I thought about the cable problem too, but that isn't a risk in my case. I also don't think the access points will be reset by anybody I just want to prepare for this possible occasional event too.

Comment: Ok, so you should also read about wifi security. Not broadcasting your SSID increases your security in the same way as using a negative filter to "encrypt" your private pictures. And if someone who resets your router can afterwards simply connect to it, then this is as bad as having someone pull out the cable from the router and connect to your network physically. Actually it is even worse, because he can reset the router quickly and then walk away and do the attack from his car across the street.

Comment: I know that SSIDs can be sniffed. The second is the reason why I want the access points to be "disconnected/banned" from the network after a reset. If there is a better network topology I'm open for that too.

Comment: The only way I can think of is that the AP needs to "know" something which is lost after reset. As this can not be a setting (because it could be guessed by the attacker) it needs to be something more random, like a key. So you could make the AP build a VPN tunnel to R. After reset the VPN key is lost => no more VPN no more connection. (obviously R should deny any non-VPN traffic).